# How to place an image by dragging and placing it in the drag proxy image position

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I found examples in adobe site only to position the object where the mouse pointer is. But i have to place the image in the position of drag proxy image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a canvas that positions the image where you need and use the canvas as a drag proxy?